# Pyramid Vision Transformer V2: Complexity of spacial reduction attention (SRA)

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, transformer, computational-complexity

I'm currently reading the paper *[PVT v2: Improved Baselines with Pyramid Vision Transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.13797)*, where the authors improve a transformer architecture that can be used as a backbone for multiple computer vision tasks such as classification, object detection, and image segmentation. In section 3.2 of the paper, they propose an approach to further reduce the complexity of the attention operation by computationally reducing the size of the inputs K and V to the attention operation.

> First, to reduce the high computational cost caused by
> attention operations, we propose linear spatial reduction attention layer
> Different from
> SRA, which uses convolutions for spatial reduction, linear
> SRA uses average pooling to reduce the spatial dimension
> (i.e., $h\times w$) to a fixed size (i.e., $P\times P$) before the attention
> operation. So linear SRA enjoys linear computational
> and memory costs like a convolutional layer. Specifically,
> given an input of size $h\times w\times c$, the complexity of SRA and
> linear SRA is:
> \begin{gathered}
> \Omega(\text { SRA })=\frac{2 h^2 w^2 c}{R^2}+h w c^2 R^2, \\
> \Omega(\text { Linear SRA })=2 h w P^2 c,
> \end{gathered}

Now, I get the idea behind the minimal complexity of Linear SRA: if we double $h,w$, or $c$, the number of times we would do average pooling would also double, and the 2 is there since we operate on $K$ and $V$. I don't see how they derived the complexity for SRA; however, maybe someone familiar with at least the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.12122) where SRA was proposed could enlighten me. Sadly, the authors haven't answered two [similar questions](https://github.com/whai362/PVT/issues/107) raised in the corresponding GitHub repo.